# Finding the Fourth Derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be a four-times differential function such that

$f(2x^2-1)=2xf(x)$

What is the value of $f''''(0)$?

A brute force approach is differentiating the given condition 4 times and finding values of $f(x)$ and its derivatives at required numbers or at a value of $x$ where the function can be simplified. Considering the LHS has a composite function and the RHS has the product of 2 functions, differentiating both sides leads to a lot of terms. I tried shifting values of $x$ but  did not find a convenient substitution to simplify the problem. How should I proceed?

Comment: Have you actually tried differentiating? I don't think the RHS leads to a lot of terms...

Comment: Initially there aren't many terms. But $2xf'(x)$ and so on lead to quite a few terms. Also, I need the LHS to equate to the RHS to, so it gets complicated

Comment: Do you have any extra conditions on $f$? This equation is linear, so has an infinite family of solutions. Note for example that $f(x)=0$ satisfies the given relation.

Comment: Nope. Just that its 4th derivative exists.

Comment: Derivating 4 times wont help, because x is a factor of $f^{(4)}$. If $f$ was 5-times differentiable, you could compute $f^{(5)}$ and with $x=0$ you'd get $f^{(4)}(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure this out a little late.

In the given functional equation, replace $x$ with $-x$.

The equation is now written as:

$f(2x^2-1)=-2xf(-x)$

But it is given that $f(2x^2-1)=2xf(x)$

Therefore, $-2xf(-x)=2xf(x)$
$=>$ $-f(-x)=f(x)$

A rather simple functional equation which can be easily differentiated 4 times.

The answer is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\cos\theta$. This tells us that $f(\cos 2\theta)=2\cos\theta f(\cos\theta)$. So, if we set $f(\cos\theta)=g(\theta)$, we now have that:

$$g(2\theta)=2\cos\theta g(\theta)$$

This is reminiscent of the double angle formula for the sine function, and we can see that:

$$\frac{g(2\theta)}{\sin2\theta}=\frac{g(\theta)}{\sin\theta}$$

Given that $f$, hence $g$, is continuous [four times differentiable $\implies$ continuous], we're thus able to say that $g(\theta)\propto\sin\theta$. This technically requires a little more work [see appendix], but is intuitively a fairly reasonable claim. Thus:

$$f(\cos\theta)=K\sin\theta\implies f(x)=K\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

We can then either differentiate or use a power series expansion to find $f''''(0)$ - if we write $\sqrt{1-x^2}=(1-x^2)^{1/2}=1-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}+O(x^6)$, which gives $f''''(0)=K\frac{-24}{8}=-3K$.

[Appendix]

Given $\frac{g(2\theta)}{\sin2\theta}=\frac{g(\theta)}{\sin\theta}$, we define $h(\theta)=\frac{g(\theta)}{\sin\theta}$, noting that $h(\theta)=h(2\theta)$, and aim to prove that $h$ is constant. Indeed, let $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $h(\theta)=h(\theta/2)=h(\theta/4)...=h(\theta/2^n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Continuity of all the functions involved means that we can take $n\to\infty$ and see that $h(\theta)=h(0)$, and thus that $h$ is constant. The desired result follows.

Comment: There must be a mistake: your function yields 2 with $x=-1/\sqrt{2}$ (and $K=1$).

Comment: Not sure I understand?

Comment: You write that necessarily $f(x)=K\sqrt{1-x^2}$. But $f(2x^2-1)\neq 2xf(x)$, for example with $x=-1/\sqrt{2}$. [edit: added the factor 2]

Comment: You're missing a factor of $2$, see the original question which gives $f(2x^2-1)=2xf(x)$

Comment: One question I have is, when we put $x=cos\theta$, aren't we discarding all values of $x$ greater than 1? How valid is it?

Comment: @SatD a few comments: 1) We're only looking for the derivative at 0, so it's valid enough for our purposes, 2) If we view $\cos$ as a function on $\mathbb{C}$, this isn't such a problem, and 3) If we're interested in $\vert x \vert >1$, then let $x=\cosh \theta$ and examine the solutions obtained there.